# C# initialize a dictionary then add to it later

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary that will be populated from the results of a query. Due to this, I do not know what data values will be going into the dictionary when I initialize it (though obviously I do know what data types will be used). I'm new to C# - how can I set this up?

In pseudocode, the dictionary structure I want is:

```
{
    "visa": [2.75, 3.33],
    "mastercard": [1.00, 4.32],
    ...
}
```

This is what I have so far, but its not compiling:

```
//initialize the dictionary but do not populate yet
Dictionary<string, List<decimal>> cardtype_total_amount;

//simulate getting the first card type from the db
string cardtype = "visa";

//initialize the "visa" key
if (!cardtype_total_amount.ContainsKey(cardtype)) cardtype_total_amount.Add(cardtype, new List<decimal>(){0, 0});

//simulate updating the values for "visa" from the db (this would happen lots of times for each card type):
cardtype_total_amount[cardtype][0] += 0.5;
cardtype_total_amount[cardtype][1] += 1.7;

//add more keys for other cardtypes, and update their totals as per above...
```

Comment: Do you know **anything** about the data? For instance, will it always consist of a string and two floats?

Comment: What do you mean "failing"? is it throwing an exception?

Comment: @KonradViltersten yes the data comes from SQL Server and will always be a string and two "money" type vars.

Comment: @YacoubMassad its not compliling

Comment: In that case, please see my answer. It's not tested but should give you a start. As for the compilation errors - it's easier to help you if you'll tell us what it says.   :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten thanks - very useful. sorry for not being specific enough :p its hard to know what i don't know!

Comment: @mulllhausen I know **precisely** what you mean. Sometimes, one doesn't realize that the actual issue is elsewhere. I noticed by the way you asked that you (a) are less savvy on C# but (b) are technically skilled. My guess i that you're coming from JS or PHP direction. Glad to be helpful. +1 for (pretty) good formulation despite the uncertainty.

Comment: @KonradViltersten thanks for the kind words. you are right - i'm mainly a python/php/js/sql programmer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think  you're just missing an initalisation!

```
//initialize the dictionary but do not populate yet
Dictionary<string, List<decimal>> cardtype_total_amount = new Dictionary<string, List<decimal>>();
```

[EDIT]
Oh, and you need some m's on your decimals below, otherwise they are doubles:

```
cardtype_total_amount[cardtype][0] += 0.5m;
```

Comment: That's done it. I actually thought I was initializing the dictionary by declaring its type. I guess not.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is what you're after. How's this?

```
Dictionary<string, List<decimal> array
  = new Dictionary<string, List<decimal>>();
```

Then for every read in (consisting of a key and value) you could do the following.

```
var addition = new { Key = "visa", Value = 3.14 };
array[addition.Key].Add(addition.Value);
```

Note that I'm not at the computer so I can have typoed a bit. Also, it depends a bit on how you're receiving the subsequent values. One at a time is assumed here. If you get a whole list of them, you can split that into dictionary itself.

```
List<Piece> bunchOfValues = ...;
Dictionary<...> results = bunchOfValues.ToDictionary(key => key.NameOrType,
  value => bunchOfValues.Where(...).Select(...));
```

Finally, when you wish to sum it all, you can go LINQ again.

```
decimal sum = arrayOfValues.Sum(element => element);
```